# what is the basis of this vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

If we have $\mathbb{F}$ be a field.

What is the basis of the $\mathbb{F}$-vector space

$
  \mathbb{F}\oplus\mathbb{F} 
$?

Comment: I'm don't understand this definition. How can you have a matrix of vector spaces?

Comment: Same as the basis of $\mathbf R^2$ as an $\mathbf R$-vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\} $ is a basis, for example. Note that $\mathbb F  \oplus \mathbb F$ is simply $\mathbb F^2$.